# SQL query - link to lookup where lookup field may be NULL

Tags: sql

I have a table, THERAPY, which contains numeric fields which link to text reference values in a lookup table, REF_CODE. I'd like to construct a query that returns a set of records from THERAPY along with the related text values from REF_CODE.

The field I'm querying on is THERAPY.PROT. PROT can be null. I want to bring back all records identified by a foreign key (EVENT_ID) along with the value from REF_CODE which corresponds to PROT. (*REF_CODE contains many lookup categories, identified by CAT_ID - that's what the CAT_ID = 1 clause is for*).

```
SELECT THER_ID, CODE_NAME FROM THERAPY t, REF_CODE r
WHERE (t.PROT = r.CODE or t.PROT is null)
AND EVENT_ID = 1234
AND r.CAT_ID = '1';
```

The problem with this is that if THERAPY.PROT = null, this query will not bring back the record at all, because there is no value in REF_CODE for PROT = null. I need a query that brings back all records from THERAPY where EVENT_ID = 1234, regardless of whether PROT is null or not. The link to REF_CODE is buggering up my query and excluding the records where PROT = null. But I still need the records in my set.

So, how can I construct a query which brings back both all records from THER where EVENT_ID = 1234 *AND* the corresponding text value from REF_CODE for PROT, regardless of whether PROT has a value or is null. Is this even possible?

Big thanks in advance for looking! Happy to answer any questions at all.

Comment: you need a left join, not an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT THER_ID
    ,ISNULL(CODE_NAME,'No Code Found') [CodeName]
FROM THERAPY t
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r
    ON t.PROT = r.CODE
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1234
    AND r.CAT_ID = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's great. There's a bit more to this actually....can't post it here it seems but will start a new question.